# Confirm Connect WMS Feed

Tags: javascript, wms, tiles, error

We currently use Pitney Bowes Confirm Connect for our highways inspections. We are trying to use our own WMS feed instead of the default Bing Maps to allow us to have access to information such as adopted highway records.

Following the guidance document you have to write a javascript settings file and drop it into the Confirm folder on our Android device (Samsung Tab 3). The application picks up the copyright text but displays a blank basemap. Can anyone see anything wrong with the JS below?

```
{
"mapSettings":{
"roads":{
"type": "WMS",
"projection": "EPSG:27700",
"projectionDef": "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=ostn02",
"attribution": "(c) Crown Copyright",
"units": "m",
"maxExtent": [250000,150000,400000,180000],
"url": "http://council.company.com/getows.ashx",
"parameters": {
"layers": ["highways"],
"url": "mapsource=Banes/AllMaps"
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Please edit your question and use the `code tags` to make it more readable.

Comment: Is that URL (the first one, starting "bathnes") supposed to be a WMS endpoint? Because I can't make it behave like one (maybe its protected) An example public WMS is here: http://129.206.228.72/cached/osm - see http://www.osm-wms.de for details.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks for the reply. I've managed to sort it out in the end. Being a newbie do I need to close this question?

Answer (score 1):

`{
"mapSettings":{
"roads":{
"type": "WMS",
"projection": "EPSG:27700",
"projectionDef": "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=ostn02",
"attribution": "(c) Crown Copyright",
"units": "m",
"maxExtent": [250000,150000,400000,180000],
"url": "http://council.company.com/getows.ashx?mapsource=Banes/AllMaps",
"parameters": {
"layers": ["highways"]
}
}
}
}`